# Web scraping using rvest for Tripadvisor rating

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

[image]I am trying to scrape tripadvisor reviews (the rating service, value, location ) using rvest (R Programming) but i am unable to do so.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Hotel_Review-g294265-d1770798-Reviews-or5-Marina_Bay_Sands-Singapore.html#REVIEWS"

reviews <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".ui_bubble_rating")


rating<-reviews%>%
  html_node(".location-review-review-list-parts-AdditionalRatings__rating--1_G5W location-review-review-list-parts-AdditionalRatings__large--IOg2u") %>% 
  html_attr("alt")
```

[Marina bay sand hotel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dprAC.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dprAC.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `html_node` you define is not in `reviews`. The ratings are already in `reviews`. You can extract them with:

```
rating <- reviews %>%
  html_attr("class") %>%
  str_extract(string = .,
              pattern = "bubble_[0-9]{2}")
```

Comment: thank you however, i m unable to identify which is service, value, location rating @ricoderks

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector with contains operator to target the parent row for each rating. Loop those rows and extract the appropriate info from the child span or div.

```
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Hotel_Review-g294265-d1770798-Reviews-or5-Marina_Bay_Sands-Singapore.html#REVIEWS"

nodes <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("[class*=subratingRow]")

df <- map_df(nodes, function(node) {

  data.frame(rating_area = node%>%html_node('div') %>% html_text(),
             rating = str_match(node%>%html_node('span')%>%html_attr('class'),'\\d+')%>%as.integer()/10,
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})
```

Comment: hello, may i know what is function(node) , which packages does it come from?

Comment: it is simply a user defined function that purrr library's map_df will apply to all elements in the input vector _nodes_.

Comment: actually i m trying to scrap the rating (bubble) in each review posted in the TripAdvisor but not the overall rating